# jvectormap - disable onclick event on regions that are predefined as selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jvectormap

As you have example like this: http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/, you can predefine selected regions by doing this:

> selectedRegions: ["Hessen", "Bayern"]

But, I want to disable those regions, so they cannot be clicked or changed states after I predefined them as selected.

Anyone have any ideas how to accomplish such a thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

return false or event to prevent default on region over to disable further events on mouse over of that particular region . Like wise to all events such as marker over , marker click etc..

Ex.

```
jQuery('#map1').bind('regionOver.jvectormap',function(event, code)
{
  if(code == 'US')
  {
     return false ; // if mouse over on 'US' region it will stop further events. like disable
  }
}
```

this many help you .

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Old post, but instead of hacking into the mouse events, you can just disable the region on the event click (predefined).

**Note:**

```
/**
 * jVectorMap version 2.0.4
 *
 * Copyright 2011-2014, Kirill Lebedev
 *
 */
```

---

**Disable click event on region:**

```
var yourMap = new jvm.Map({
    map: 'world_mill_en',
    container: $('#map'),
    ....
    ....
    onRegionClick: function (e, code) {
        // check your code here
        if (code == 'somethingYouWantToDisable') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }            
    }
});
```

---

If you need to disable other events regarding region, take a look at these as well:

```
    onRegionTipShow: function (e, label, code) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    onRegionSelected: function (e, code, isSelected, selectedRegions) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir. can you add multiple entrys from a varible containg a array? to " if (code == 'somethingYouWantToDisable')"